# Send a second request nb of times as nb of items returned for first request using Karate

Tags: karate

I need to send 2 requests in a Scenario Outline. Ex:

```
Background:
* url 'someurl'

  Scenario Outline:
  * path <owner_id>, 'cats'
  * method get
  * status 200
  here I need to get ids of cats from response as {"cats": [{"cat_id": "xx"}, {"cat_id": "yy"}...]}

  * path <owner_id>, <cat_id>, 'kittens'
  * method get
  * status 200
  Examples:
  |owner_id|
  |bill_id |
  |kate_id | and so on
```

Is it possible to send the second request (kittens' retrieving) for each cat_id from the first request and this for each owner_id?

I tried another way:

```
Background:
* url 'someurl'

  Scenario Outline:
  * def cats = call read('GetCats.feature')
 then store cat_ids as here:
  * def catsIds = cats.c[*].id (I get an error "javascript evaluation failed: cats.c[*]id, <eval>:1:6 Expected an operand but found *") 
  OR
  * def catsIds = karate.mapWithKey(cats.c[*].id, 'cat_id')

  * path <owner_id>, <cat_id>, 'kittens'
  * method get
  * status 200
  Examples:
  |owner_id|
  |bill_id |
  |kate_id | ...
```

And here is GetCats.feature

```
 Scenario:
 * url 'someurl'
 * path 'cats'
 * method get
 * status 200
 * def c = response
```

I was thinking about karate.repeat but can we use it for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything is possible, you can call other features, all data is in scope etc.

You made a mistake here, note the `$`:

```
* def catsIds = $cats.c[*].id
```

Refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#get

Comment: Thanks @Peter Thomas. I edited my examples, I added <owner_id> in path for 2nd request (to get kittens). Storing cats' ids works, but after how I can iterate in these ids? The question is: is it possible to do a sort of Scenario Outline in another Scenario Outline? get kittens for every cat for every owner? Do you recommend another way? Thanks

Comment: @nirind I think you are over-complicating. I can't understand your example or question, so simplify it as far as possible (3-5 lines max) and ask another question please

Comment: Ok I try again: I need to make smth like: I get cats for owner A, then in the same scenario I need to get kittens for EACH cat of owner A. I don't know in advance how much cats has the owner A. Then the same thing for owner B and so on. The list of owners comes from external job, I don't know in advance how many owners I will have